# Cannot find module error from docker-composer (only on windows)

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

We are trying to create a container running node.js, using docker (docker-compose, as we intend to add mongodb afterwards as well).

We are copying the **package.json** in Dockerfile and then mounting a volume in **docker-compose.yml** which contains the source code to be executed.

Our project structure is as follow.

[image: Project structure]

We want source folder to be mounted as volume.

Our **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "node_package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "node_package inside node_dir for node_service running on node_container",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node source/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.0"
  }
}
```

Our **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /node_dir
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
```

Our **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:

  node_service:

     build: .

     container_name: node_container

     user: node

     working_dir: "/node_dir"

     ports:
     - "8080:3000"

     volumes:
     - ./source:/node_dir/source

     command: npm start
```

Now when we run this on macOS, it works. It mounts the source folder as volume and then executes **command npm start**. But when we try the same on windows we get the following error

**Cannot find module 'node_dir/source/index.js'**

Why it is working on mac but not on windows?

Here is our **index.js** file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => {console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)})
```

When we copy source folder in Dockerfile then it works on Windows. But if we don't copy source folder in Dockerfile and mount it as volume in docker-compose.yml then **command npm start** does not work.

Comment: Have you tried removing the node_modules folder and running 'npm install' again on the windows machine?

Comment: You mean that I should run 'npm install' on host windows machine or on container image?

Comment: Well you say 'we try the same on windows' - so I assume you have a bash shell running on windows (or something like that), and you're using some svn (git etc) to grab the repo, so by default you'd have to run npm install anyway, right? I'm just suggesting deleting the node_modules folder and running it again.

Comment: No we aren't using any repo. Its just a simple setup project. We just copied files manually. We are copying package.json and running directly npm install on the docker image.

Comment: We also tried removing modules folder and running it again. It didn't changed anything because its throwing error on the index.js file mounted as a volume on docker (running on windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because some node module need to compile so when run `npm i` npm get Compatible module with OS i.e. the `node_module` folder in Windows is different with Mac.

best solution: isolate node_module from bind mount in docker-compose.
so edit `docker-compose.yml`
from:

```
volumes:
   - ./source:/node_dir/source
```

to:

```
volumes:
   - /node_dir/node_modules # isolate node_modules for compatible os
   - ./source:/node_dir/source
```

Comment: Isn't node_modules is already isolated in our current scenario? because docker-compose.yml is mounting source folder from host to container inside node_dir directory. But node_modules is in the node_dir directory (generated by npm install on the container using Dockerfile, one level higher than mounted source folder). I don't understand how declaring "/node_dir/node_modules" in volume will isolate it for compatible OS?

Comment: no, when you bind node_dir  directory to docker container, file system is same host OS not linux file system. when isolate node_modules by above technique node_modules move to a temporary volume that file system is base on linux file system and is completely compatible.

Comment: Well it's still not working. Error is same even after isolating the /node_dir/node_modules.

Comment: oh, now focus on the code know index.js not mount (or copy) in container so  you must copy index.js to container /node_dir to solve problem.

Comment: I want index.js to be in source folder. I also checked even if I do not mount / bind / attach any volume and copy the whole source folder using COPY command in docker file after NPM install ... It still gives me the error. If I place index.js file in node_dir folder (same directory as package.json and node_modules) it works, but if I move it to the source folder it does not work. It doesn't matter if I use source folder or node_modules folder as volume or not. Its simply not working when I put index.js inside source folder, even when I have specified that in my package.json.

Comment: you must add this line to end of Dockerfile: "COPY index.js ./
"

Comment: Yes I did and it didn't made any difference. Adding index.js won't be helpful like this as my index.js is inside the source folder. And i tried copying everything but it is not working when I refer it inside the source folder.

Comment: I can help you in telegram messager. [my username: masihjahangiri](https://t.me/masihjahangiri)